# Interactive Plots in Jupyter notebook not shown on Github

Tags: python, matplotlib, github, jupyter-notebook

I have Interactive Plots in Jupyter notebook but those plots are not shown on Github once I upload my notebook to Github, any suggestions around it?
I even save notebook's widget state. Below is a sample interactive python plot if you want to try:

```
from IPython.html.widgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as wg
from IPython.display import display 
from numpy import pi


def pltFunc(f):

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
    x = np.arange(0,2*pi,0.01)
    y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*x*f)
    y2 = np.cos(2*np.pi*x*g) + np.sin(np.pi*x*g)

    plt.subplot(221)
    plt.text(3, 2, r'$f(t) = \sin(2\pi \times$' + str((f)) +  't)' , 
                             {'color': 'b', 'fontsize': 16, 'ha': 'center', 'va': 'center',})
    plt.plot(x, y1, 'b', linewidth=2)
    plt.title('Sine Signal - change f')
    plt.xlabel('t', {'color': 'k', 'fontsize': 20})
    plt.ylabel('f(t)', {'color': 'k', 'fontsize': 20})
    plt.ylim([-2.5,2.5])
    plt.xlim([0,2*pi])
    plt.xticks((0, pi, 2*pi), ('$0$','$\pi$','$2\pi$'), color='k', size=20)
    plt.yticks((-2, 0, 2), ('-2','$0$','+2'), color='k', size=20)
    plt.show()




f_slide = wg.FloatSlider(value=1.5,min=0,max=3,step=0.1)
interact(pltFunc, f = f_slide)
```

Even they don't show up if you download the notebook as pdf as latex

Comment: Have you looked at https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github/

Comment: @Skam yes I tried that, it creates an html, once push it to github, if you open it nothing shows up like a notebook on github

Comment: I dont think Github supports interactive widgets in a jupyter notebook.